# Sync SQL Server Transaction Logs to Redshift

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, aws, data-synchronization, redshift

I am researching the plausibility of syncing SQL Server logs to an AWS Redshift data warehouse.

Redshift has the COPY command to do parallel loads from S3 to Redshift already. Additionally, there are many 3rd party tools that promise *near* synchronous replication of the transaction logs.

1. Are these 3rd party tools the only solution?
2. Are these tools faster than an S3 COPY?
3. Is there an SQL Server based solution that still includes Redshift?

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask the vendors of these tools if they support your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing exists natively from SQL Server so 3rd party is your best bet. Homegrown is not recommended because SQL Server's transaction log format is not published so it'll be a pretty steep curve.

sp_BlitzErik's suggestion to talk to the vendors is the best place to start. If you don't have the right contacts or not enough vendors to evaluate, check out the RS data integration partners on https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/partners/[1](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/partners/)

You can also contact AWS directly or post a feature request on the AWS RS forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=155&start=0